# How to algebraically derive the inverse of $x + e^x = y$?

Tags: inverse-function, lambert-w

Okay, so here's an approach I took:

$$ x + e^x = y $$
$$ e^{[x + e^x]} = e^y $$
$$ e^x e^{e^x} = e^y $$
$$ e^x = W(e^y) $$
$$ x = \ln{W(e^y)} $$
Where $W(z)$ is Lambert W function.

This works, but if I feed the initial problem into Wolfram Alpha, it gives me a different result:
$$ x = y - W(e^y) $$

This solution looks cleaner and works better for the purposes of the problem I'm trying to solve. However since I don't have much experience doing math with the W function and utilizing its properties, I failed to figure out, how I derive it myself. Please, may someone explain to me, how?

Comment: From $$e^xe^{e^x}=e^y$$ and $$e^x=y-x\Rightarrow (y-x)e^{y-x}=e^y\Rightarrow y-x=W(e^y)$$...

Comment: @QuantumPotatoïd I've already accepted another answer, but thank you for your variant as well! When you both wrote it down this way, it made me wonder how I missed it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $W(e^y)e^{W(e^y)} = e^y$ by definition of the Lambert function, hence $W(e^y) = e^{y-W(e^y)}$ and finally $x = \ln W(e^y) = y - W(e^y)$.

Comment: Ohhh, It is this simple! Now I feel ashamed, that I couldn't figure it out by myself, I must be too tired at this moment. Thank you!

Comment: @YukiEndo  No problem, you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

**1)**

$$x+e^x=y$$

We see, the [elementary function term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) on the left-hand side of the equation is a polynomial without a univariate factor and in dependence of two $\mathbb{C}$-algebraically independent monomials ($x,e^x$). Therefore we don't know how to solve the equation for $x$ by rearranging for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of elementary functions that we can read from the equation.
We therefore cannot see if the elementary function on the left-hand side has a partial inverse that is an elementary function.

Furthermore, for algebraic $y$, the equation is an irreducible algebraic equation of $x$ and $e^x$. The theorem in Lin 1983 and the theorem in Chow 1999 state that such kind of equations don't have solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) and in the explicit elementary numbers respectively, if Schanuel's conjecture is true.

**2)**

Lambert W is the inverse relation of the function $x\mapsto xe^x$.

To see if our equation is solvable in terms of Lambert W, we try to rearrange the equation into the product form that's required for Lambert W.

This is a longer way, but without any tricks.

A sum equation can be rearranged to a product equation in each case.

$$x+e^x=y$$
$$e^x=y-x$$
$$1=(y-x)e^{-x}$$
$$(y-x)e^{-x}=1$$
$$(y-x)e^{y-x}=e^{y}$$
$$y-x= W(e^y)$$
$$x=y-W(e^y)$$

Answer (score 0):

$x=y-W(e^{y})$

The general equation:

$e^x +x=y$

Subtract x from both sides

$e^{x}=y-x$

Multiply both by $e^{-x}$

$1=(y-x)e^{-x}$

Multiply both by $e^{y}$

$(y-x)e^{y-x}=e^{y}$

Taking Lambert W of both get:

$(y-x)=W(e^{y})$

Therefore:

$x=y-W(e^{y})$

Comment: Could you please replace your first equation by the requested equation of the original question? And could you please set $x$ in your second line?